# Sample size when adding two means of different groups

Tags: t-test

I want to compare a theoretical mean to a measured mean. But I determine this theoretical mean from adding two measured means. For example, let's say I want to determine if mixing a shade of white paint with a shade of black paint yields a particular gray paint (let’s pretend I can quantify paint color).

I find the mean hexadecimal color of the white paint by measuring several independent samples of Eggshell white (n=20 different paint cans) and I do the same for the Midnight black paint (n=28), lets pretend these all come from different companies so there is variation between each paint of the same color. I also have a gray paint that I measure the color of using, again, several samples (n=28).

I want to then ask if I were to *theoretically* mix the white and black paint (based on the individual samples I measured) would they add up to the gray paint's measured color? In other words ask: If I add the mean value of the white paint, to the mean value of the black paint would this theoretical value differ from my actual measurements of the gray paint’s color?

So I have the sample size, mean, and std dev of the gray paint I measured. I have the mean of the theoretical gray paint (found by adding the means of white and black paint) and the std dev of the theoretical gray paint (found by quadrating the std dev of the white and black samples). But what I am missing is the sample size of the theoretical gray paint, because I cannot simply add the white and black samples sizes together, as they are different colors.

I need to perform a t-test to ask is my measured gray paint significantly different than the theoretical gray paint? My hunch would be to use the smaller sample size of the two paints (n=20) as a conservative value but I'm unsure if this is appropriate, because technically this theoretical value does not have a number of samples associated with it.

Comment: Do not think it works that way. Paint has particles, the particle size influences the color, and for paints with different particle sizes, mixing them will produce different results, that is, I think. Moreover, some paints can be mixed, and others not so well.

Comment: You don't appear to be asking a statistical question, but rather one about the physics of paint and the perception of colors.

Comment: It was a simple example to explain a more abstract problem I am working on. I couldn't care less about paint. I'm actually doing work with genetic interactions of genes but that's not so easy to explain compared to paint. The general question is the same in terms of getting a theoretical mean from two independent sample groups and asking what the sample size is. Don't get hung up on the physical details of paint particles mixing or the philosophical question of color perception

Comment: sorry you're too simple to understand that